# 3 Consecutive date fetching in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch city details in table which temperature is less then 0 and it should be 3 consecutive days.
In record date between 1/1/2021 to 31/10/2021.

Sample output:

```
City      temprature  day 
Texas     -2          3/1/2021
Texas     -4          4/1/2021
Texas     -1          5/1/2021
New York  -3          21/3/2021
New York  -6          22/3/2021
New York  -5          23/3/2021
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show us some sample table data _and the expected result_ - all as formatted text (not images,) and also your current query attempt. I.e. [mcve].

Comment: City  temperature  day  country

Comment: Texas -2 1-1 2021

Comment: Hey, edit the question instead. And remember that the clearer a problem is, the better and faster the answers will be.

Comment: Thats not how you post a question, post the details in your question, not in your comments, where is your code, what have you tried so far. We will help but not write.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL query to find the number of customers who shopped for 3 consecutive days in month of January 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425631/sql-query-to-find-the-number-of-customers-who-shopped-for-3-consecutive-days-in)   Or you could try to use that info for your problem......

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query -

```
SELECT T.City, T.temprature, T.day
  FROM (SELECT T.*, COUNT(*) OVER(ORDER BY day RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) cnt_days
          FROM your_table T
         WHERE temprature < 0)
 WHERE cnt_days = 3
```